# Loading highcharts with bower and Yeoman gives reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, bower, yeoman

I have a highcharts graph that **works fine as a stand alone HTML document**.

When I try to integrate it into my web application infrastructure generated by Yeoman I get an error:

```
ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:343:5), <anonymous>:3:5)
    at fire (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3187:31)
    at Object.self.add [as done] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3246:7)
    at jQuery.fn.ready (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3496:25)
    at jQuery.fn.init (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:2927:10)
    at jQuery (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:75:10)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:343:5), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at eval (native)
    at Function.jQuery.extend.globalEval (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:343:5)
    at domManip (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5290:15) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13550(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10225invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:9696nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:9093compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:8397publicLinkFn @ angular.js:8277lazyCompilation @ angular.js:8615boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:8414controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:9143update @ angular-route.js:968Scope.$broadcast @ angular.js:17552(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:643processQueue @ angular.js:15961(anonymous function) @ angular.js:15977Scope.$eval @ angular.js:17229Scope.$digest @ angular.js:17045Scope.$apply @ angular.js:17337done @ angular.js:11572completeRequest @ angular.js:11778requestLoaded @ angular.js:11711
exporting.js?_=1461240740374:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
```

On the stand alone document the header file looks like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I'm using the same header file in my Yeoman web application view, but Bower seems to default to a different version of Jquery, and I get that error.

How can I solve this?

Comment: It looks like scripts are loaded async. can you switch into sync?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that means, but how can I switch to sync?